# Horizontal Twitter Feed

Tags: html, css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3

What I want to do seems like a simple thing, but after hours of Googling, doesn't seem to be.

I have a webpage created with Bootstrap. I want to display the 3 most recent tweets from a specific user horizontally at the bottom of the page. Something like this:

```
------------ ------------ --------------
|          | |          | |            |
| Tweet 1  | | Tweet 2  | |   Tweet 3  |
|          | |          | |            |
|          | |          | |            |
------------ ------------ --------------
```

I would love to be able to style them and put them in columns so it is responsive.

This is the only code I have tried because I can't find anything else that seems helpful:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Anthony">Tweets by Anthony</a>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: You should provide some code (what have you tried so far). It would help not only to us, but to you too since you would get a code with a solution.

Comment: I didn't include any code because all I seem to be able to even get close with is the basic Twitter embed code. I have no clue how to style it. I will include it in my question.

Comment: did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: @sudoman yes, the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873306/add-border-between-bootstrap-columns-from-twitter-loop/40880001#40880001

Comment: I need a solution that doesn't use a wordpress plugin

Comment: ^ Ignore that, found [this.](https://github.com/sonnyt/Tweetie)